# rpm file conflict after alien conversion

Tags: fedora, kde, rpm, deb, alien

I have a program for which I generate a .deb file. The .deb file works fine on the systems I have tried it on (also tested with lintian). Previously it has worked to use alien to convert this to .rpm and install it on Suse. However it is now about a year since I tried it the last time and now I get an error when trying to install the alien made rpm on Fedora 11, I get this error:

```
file /usr/share/icons/default.kde from install of testpkg-0.2-2.i386 conflicts with file from package kdelibs3-3.5.10-13.fc11.1.i586
```

Listing the content of the rpm file:

```
$ rpm -qlp testpkg-0.2-2.i386.rpm
/
/usr
/usr/games
/usr/games/testpkg
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libfmod-3.75.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/app-install
/usr/share/app-install/icons
/usr/share/app-install/icons/testpkg.png
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/testpkg.desktop
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/testpkg
/usr/share/doc/testpkg/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/testpkg/copyright
/usr/share/games
/usr/share/games/testpkg
/usr/share/games/testpkg/images
/usr/share/games/testpkg/images/bb.dat
/usr/share/games/testpkg/images/bb_bg.dat
/usr/share/games/testpkg/images/bubblemad_8x8.png
/usr/share/games/testpkg/images/goldfont.png
/usr/share/games/testpkg/lvl
/usr/share/games/testpkg/lvl/lvl001.txt
/usr/share/games/testpkg/lvl/lvl002.txt
/usr/share/games/testpkg/lvl/lvl003.txt
/usr/share/games/testpkg/lvl/lvl004.txt
/usr/share/games/testpkg/lvl/lvl005.txt
/usr/share/games/testpkg/lvl/lvl006.txt
/usr/share/games/testpkg/lvl/lvl007.txt
/usr/share/games/testpkg/music
/usr/share/games/testpkg/music/alfa.it
/usr/share/games/testpkg/music/beta.it
/usr/share/games/testpkg/sounds
/usr/share/games/testpkg/sounds/bounce.wav
/usr/share/games/testpkg/sounds/click.wav
/usr/share/games/testpkg/sounds/warning.wav
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons/default.kde
/usr/share/icons/default.kde/16x16
/usr/share/icons/default.kde/16x16/apps
/usr/share/icons/default.kde/16x16/apps/testpkg.png
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man6
/usr/share/man/man6/testpkg.6.gz
```

Am I wrong in putting the kde icons in */usr/share/icons/default.kde* which seem to be a symbolic link ? It's a symbolic link on both Kubuntu 9.10 and Fedora 11 though.

Sounds like a common situation that the same directory is needed for different packages, so why is it a conflict ?

Answer (score 1):

You already have explained the problem with trampling over the path that belongs to a different package in detail yourself, I cannot add more than "so don't do it".

Read http://specs.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#directory_layout, install the icons under `/usr/share/icons/hicolor`.